# Changing date format globally

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I am using PHP and mysql and using either `Date` or `DateTime` to save dates in mysql database. On site I have been displaying dates the way they are saved in database.

But now I want to show dates EVERYWHERE on site using one format:

```
April 17 2013
```

or

```
April 17 2013 12:20:50
```

I know I can use `date` and `strtotime` functions to display dates in above format. However there are a lot of places where I have date displaying code. So I am looking to automate the process where my current code works and displays dates in above format.

Any idea of how **mysql trigger** or some php magic could be created that converts all dates run through SELECT query automatically without changing my sql or php code since I have a lot of places in my code and it would be overkill to change code at all places?

**For Example:**

**Date Saved in DB:** 2013-04-16 12:41:26

**SELECT QUERY:** `SELECT * FROM myTable`

**PHP:** `echo $row->dated;` displays `2013-04-16 12:41:26`

I want that without changing my php code, dates should be shown in above mentioned format globally on whole site.

Any ideas please how it could be achieved ?

Comment: Issues of data display should normally be handled at the application level. Just return the date in normal SQL format and use your application code (php? or perhaps a bit of javascript?) to handle the formatting. I prefer any method that allows the user to adjust the formatting to suit their locality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly format in via query using `DATE_FORMAT()`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(myDate, '%M %d %Y %h:%i') myDate
FROM   TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c096d/5)

and echo in your PHP: `$row->myDate`

---

MySQL Trigger doesn't project values and It is only fired during `CrUD` operations.

Comment: Thats's what I like about SO, learning something new everyday! Didn't know about that one.

Comment: As I said I have lot of places in code, I am looking for trigger that does it automatically for me so that I don't have to modify my code. Any idea of how mysql trigger could be created that converts all dates run through `SELECT` query automatically ?

Comment: @Dev01 mysql trigger doesn't project values. and It is only trigger during `CrUD` operations.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you an alternative approach which i love to use.

You should use the `epoch` time. An epoch time is basicly the number of second that has passed since `1 January 1970`

1. One if the benefits i love is that it is very easy to calculate
   differences in time since you are just dealing with number of
   seconds and not a complicated format such as `sec min hrs`
2. Another benefit is that it is very easy to store since its a
   integer so you can store it in a sql db and have your php code understand it without worrying about the format and things like that.

In php, if you use the `time()` function, it will return the epoch time.
And if you ever want to display it in a user friendly way. you can use the following code:

```
$epoch = time();
$dt = new DateTime("$epoch"); // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // output = 2012-08-15 00:00:00
```

As you can see, the format of the date is very flexible and thus easy to use.

A nice example to find the date 1 week ago:

```
$epoch = time() - 604800; //604800 seconds = 7 days
$dt = new DateTime("$epoch"); // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // output = 2012-08-15 00:00:00
```